# How to read and get sum of integers out of text file?

Tags: c++, file, text

I have already made a code for it, but its very poor. I would like to know how can I get all integers and sum out of it faster. Thank you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d, m, s, b = 0, l = 0, vm, vs, mv, ms;;
    ifstream file("File.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file >> d;
        cout << d << endl;
        file >> m >> s;
        cout << m << " " << s << endl;
        b += m;
        l += s;
        file >> m >> s;
        cout << m << " " << s << endl;
        b += m;
        l += s;
        file >> m >> s;
        cout << m << " " << s << endl;
        b += m;
        l += s;
        file.close();
    }
    else cout << "File has not opened." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lets say there are 4 lines like that : first line - 3, second line - 1 and 2, 3rd line - 5,6 and so on. How can I get a sum out of second and other lines ?

Comment: Thank you very much vsoftco !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. I assume you need 2 partial sums. What you can do is to replace all of the content of the `if` block with:

```
file >> d; // read the first number
cout << d << endl;
while(file >> m >> s) // keep reading 2 numbers
{
    b += m;
    l += s;
    cout << m << " " << s << endl;
}
```

There is no need to manually close the file, the destructor will take care of it automatically at the end of program (scope).